# Get user's facebook access token 60 days with user_groups permission

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to get a 60 days access token with user_groups permission on Facebook.

Three ways :

- 1) Access Token from GRAPH API
- 2) Access Token from developper account with personnal APP
- 3) Access Token from no-developper account with personnal APP

In the first way, we can add user_groups permission, but, we can't know the secret token of Graph API, so impossible to perform an exchange and get a 60 days token

In the second way, we can add user_groups permission and perform an exchange and get a 60 days token, with a developper account

In third way, i try to authorize user_groups permission for users of my application (no-developper account), but Facebook says "The user_groups permission is only granted for apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission." I made a little PHP script, just login and get most commented posts of groups in wich we are registered. It's seems not good for Facebook, so, what can i do for having this permission from FB ?

Comment: _“so, what can i do for having this permission from FB ?”_ – at the moment: Nothing, because as the part you quoted already _clearly told you_, you simply won’t get that permission approved for general usage. (They are working on a new permission that will give access to the groups the user is an admin of – but that is not available yet.)

Comment: Not usefull, so why purpose this permission in apps if nobody can have it ?

Comment: It simply created too much spam by apps auto-posting in user groups, so it was restricted so that apps on any platform that already has a Facebook client will not get it any more.